# Insertion Sort vs. Merge Sort: which is faster depending on array?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, complexity-theory, mergesort, insertion-sort

Suppose that we are given an array A already sorted in increasing order. Which is asymptotically faster, insertion-sort or merge-sort?

Like wise, suppose we are given an array B sorted in decreasing order, so it needs to be reversed. Which is now asymptotically faster?

I'm having a hard time grasping this, I already know that insertion-sort is better for smaller data sets and merge-sort is better for larger data sets. However I'm not sure why one is faster than the other depending on whether or not the data set is already sorted or not.

Answer (score 2):

Speaking about worst case, the merge sort is faster with `O(N logN)` against `O(N^2)` for insertion sort. However, another characteristic of an algorithm is omega - best case complexity, which is `Omega(N)` for insertion sort against `Omega(N logN)` of merge sort.
The latter can be explained when looking at the algorithms at hand:

1. Merge sort works by dividing the array in half (if possible), recursively sorting those halves and merging them. Look how it does not depend on the actual order of elements: we will do recursive calls regardless of whether the part we're sorting is already in order (unless it's the base case).
2. Insertion sort seeks for the first element which is out of the desired order, and shifts it to the left, until it's in order. If there's no such index, no shifting will occur, and the algorithm will finish, doing only `O(N)` comparisons.

However, the merge sort is quite fixable w.r.t. best running time! You can check if the part at hand is already sorted before going into recursion. This will not change the worst case complexity of `O(N logN)` (however, the constant will double), but will bring the best case complexity to `Omega(N)`.
In the case where the data is sorted in the reverse order, the insertion sort's worst case will show itself, since we'll have to move each element (in the order of iteration) from its position to the first position, doing `N(N-1)/2` swaps, which belongs to `O(N^2)`. The merge sort, however, still takes `O(N logN)` because of its recursive approach.

Comment: what do you mean by "(unless it's the base case)." ?

Comment: Most library implementations of merge sort are variations of [bottom up merge sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Bottom-up_implementation), usually a hybrid of insertion sort and merge sort, such as [timsort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort), that take advantage of increasing or decreasing sequence runs.

Comment: Wikipedia calls this [natural merge sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Natural_merge_sort).

Comment: @EmilB For recursive algorithms, the base case is the case when you do not recurse, but solve the problem in a different, usually brute-force or trivial way. In the case of merge sort, it may be a subarray of 0 or 1 length (because it's already sorted, you don't have do anything and just return).